# how to read data from xml file

Tags: asp.net, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<user>
  <username>prince</username> 
  <password>user1</password> 
</user>
```

This is my xml file name as user.xml.

Now  when i click the button in the page, i need to get the data from that file and  place  that data  in variable like:

```
string strusername =  data  cmg from  xml file (prince)
string strPassword =  data  cmg from  xml file (password)
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this with syntax?

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) is the modern way to do what you want.

```
 XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("user.xml");
 string strusername =  xDoc.Descendants(XName.Get("username")).First().Value;
 string strPassword = xDoc.Descendants(XName.Get("password")).First().Value;
```

Comment: Any reason for using XName.Get instead of just using the implicit conversion from string? `Descendants("username")`...

Comment: Descendants doesn't have version that take string as an argument, isn't it?

Comment: Works great, if you're on .NET 3.5 and up - use XmlDocument on .NET 3.0 and below

Comment: The best and simplest answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28VS.71%29.aspx), [XmlTextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader%28VS.71%29.aspx) and [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28VS.71%29.aspx).  They are all relatively straight forward to use.