# read content in xml in Umbraco 7

Tags: xml, umbraco7

I need read a xml file and display the content in a page of Umbraco 7, I have created a new partial view, but I not have idea of how load the xml and display the content in the partial view, somebody could say me how I can do it?

Comment: Not really Umbraco related once you have the partial view in place? Or am I misunderstanding? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542326/how-to-read-data-from-xml-file

Comment: I create the partial view and now I am loading the XML, but the loop is breaking in the first field found and ignore the rest